# Running each TestNG suite in different process

Tags: maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

My pom.xml defines two TestNG suites as follows:

```
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.19</version>
   <configuration combine.children="override">
     <forkCount>1</forkCount>
     <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
     <suiteXmlFiles>
       <suiteXmlFile>suite-1.xml</suiteXmlFile>
       <suiteXmlFile>suite-2.xml</suiteXmlFile>
     </suiteXmlFiles>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>
</plugins>
```

I would like to run each suite in a separate jvm process one after another (without overlapping execution). I have tried playing around with different parameters but not able to get this working. Is there a way to do this?

```
start process P1
run suite-1.xml
stop process P1
start process P2
run suite-2.xml
stop process P2
```

Comment: First why do you use suites? Why is it necessary to run them into different processes/threads? What could/should it proof? Are those tests really unit tests? Furthermore you are using an extreme old version of surefire plugin ?...